# How can I create GRID from IMG?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, convert, image, esri-grid-format

I  would like to convert an img to grid in ArcMap 10.2. I tried it in two ways:

1. In Conversion tools with the Raster to other format tool, where I adjusted the GRID format and the output workspace was a gdb
2. In ArcCatalog with right click on the image I choosed Export --> Raster to Different Format. Here I didn't adjust any extension and I tried to save the output raster into a gdb and also into a simple folder.

My problem is that the result is in FGDBR format in every case. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Copy Raster tool. It's converted things to GRID for me in the past quite reliably.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000

Comment: Just don't add an extension and it's a grid. Beware of the storage requirements: Names must be less than 13 characters, no spaces, must not start with a number, path must be less than a certain length... If there's no extension but you're putting it into a file geodatabase then it will be a file geodatabase raster, if you want a grid pick folder as the storage location.